# Hiding div using css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

hey I'm currently having a problem on manipulating my div's, see i have this code here that displays a div search result like the ones in google. inside it is another div "overlay" hidden with a "position:fixed;" style and it only displays when the user clicks on the hyperlink Abstract then it will be hidden again once they clicked the overlay div

**Problem :** once i click on the abstract div, it will return to the state hidden

```
<div class="SearchResults">';
echo "      <span class='top'>";
echo "          <a href='#'>";
echo "              <h3>". $title ."</h3>";
echo "          </a>";
echo "          <br />";
echo "          <h5 class='sub'>";
echo                $abstract;
echo "          </h5>";
echo "      </span>";
echo "      <span class='bottom'>";
echo "          <span class='bottomLeft'>";
echo "              <a href='#' class='options' onclick='showOverlay(". $run['id'] .")'>";
echo "                  Abstract";
echo "              </a>";
echo "              <span style='margin:0px 5px;'>|</span>";
echo "              <a target='_blank' href='view.php?filename=NKTI  Proceedings  vol. 1 no. 1 Feb.  1996' class='options'>";
echo "                  Full Article";
echo "              </a>";  
echo "          </span>";
echo "          <div class='overlay' id='". $run['id'] ."' onclick='hideOverlay(". $run['id'] .")'> ";
echo "              <div class='abstract'>";
echo "                      <h1>".$title."</h1><br /><br /><br />";
echo                        $run['abstract'];
echo "              </div>";
echo "          </div>";
echo "          <span class='bottomRight'>";
echo "              <p class='label'>volume 1, January - April 2015</p>";
echo "          </span>";
echo "      </span>";
echo "      <br style='clear:both;'/>";
echo "</div>";
```

here's my css code

```
.abstract
{
z-index:300;
box-shadow:0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
padding:20px;
margin:5% auto;
height:500px;
width:80%;
background:white;
overflow:auto;
overflow-wrap:break-word;
text-align:justify;
-webkit-transition:1s;
line-height:1.5;
}
.overlay
{
-webkit-transition:1s;
display:none;
opacity:0;
width:100%;
height:100vh;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:200;
}
```

and also my javascript code

```
    function showOverlay(id)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style['display'] = "block";
        document.getElementById(id).style['opacity'] = "1";
    }

    function hideOverlay(id)
    {

        document.getElementById(id).style['opacity'] = "0";
        document.getElementById(id).style['display'] = "none";

    }
```

note: i just want to achieve the effect like facebook makes when you click an image on the news feed.

Comment: If you are asking about a client–side problem, better to post the client–side code.

Comment: no actually i'm just asking if i could modify the code so that when i click on the abstract the overlay won't disappear

Comment: If that's all, then remove the onclick listener that does that (i.e. `onclick='hideOverlay(...)'`). PS you can do `onclick='showOverlay(this)'` then in the function `function hideOverlay(element)` and *element* will reference the element so you can then do `element.style.opacity = ...` and so on. No passing ID. ;-)

Comment: i can't really do that i want the users to click on the black background of the div "overlay" but when they click on the child div of "overlay" which is "abstract" the div won't disappear

Comment: Can you post a fiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: keeping it simple , there are many ways to hide some element using css , opacity = 0 , visibility = hidden and display = none. now go and change their css as you want.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a1z1mwfn/


this is the thing im talking about but the showOverlay doesn't work on jsfiddle i don't know why

Comment: @ Abhinav Gauniyal

i know that already, what im saying is when i click on the div class= "abstract" the hideOverlay() function executes

Comment: guys i somehow found the similar thing i wanted to make

https://code.facebook.com/posts/605190406179047/developing-facebook-s-new-photo-viewer/?__mref=message_bubble


im posting this so that it might help someone making the same thing . :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the listener to run when the click comes from the div, but not from a child element. If that's correct, you can check where the click came from and only do the action if it came from an element you want to respond to.

I've done it by passing *this* and *event* to the function, but there are other ways to do the same thing:

```
<div id="foo" onclick="hideOverlay(this, event)" style="border: 1px solid #dddddd">
  <p  style="background-color: #aaccff">Some content</p>
</div>
<button onclick="showOverlay('foo')">Show overlay</button>

<script>

function hideOverlay(el, evt) {
  if (el && evt) {
    el.style.display = evt.target == el ? 'none' : '';
  }
}

function showOverlay(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (el) el.style.display = '';
}

</script>
```

Clicking on the P doesn't hide the div because the click it gets bubbles up from another element, you have to click on the div to hide it. Once it's hidden, clicking the button shows it again.

Note that when showing an element, it's preferred to set *display* to `''` (empty string) so it returns to the default or whatever the element has inherited, you don't need to set the correct value for the various types of element.

Comment: thanks dude i've been having this problem since yesterday, but i just tried your code you nailed it man. I almost gave up on this. thanks again